# Does startAdvertisingPeer work when app enters background?

Tags: ios7, core-bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I'd like the app to advertise a service even when the app enters the background. With Core Bluetooth, this is possible by setting bluetooth-peripheral for UIBackgroundModes.

Does anyone know if the same can be achieved with MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was at WWDC this year I went to a Developer Lab for Multipeer Connectivity and was told  by an Apple engineer that no, service advertisers and browsers will not work in the background.

That said, I've been successfully communicating with connected peers with an app running in the background using a background task, but I have not been able to advertise or browse.

Comment: Thanks that's very useful to know. I'll be doing some testing to try to make this work as well.

Comment: Were you able to maintain the peer connection alive for a long time using background tasks?

Comment: I'm curious about this too.  How can I maintain that connection so that my chat app can still receive notifications from others in the chat room?

Comment: Can you please share some sample code... that how you are maintaining connection in background and how you are receiving/sending messages...

Comment: Did you find anything out about that? I'm trying to do something similar, but don't know how to connect to a device that's having the app running in background